# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

While I am running the simple code as below I have two errors as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace::std;

template <class Type>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack (int max):stack(new Type[max]), top(-1), maxsize(max){}
    ~Stack (void) {delete []stack;}
    void Push (Type &val);
    void Pop (void) {if (top>=0) --top;}
    Type& Top (void) {return stack[top];}
    //friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, Stack&);
private:
    Type *stack;
    int top;
    const int maxSize;
};

template <class Type>
void Stack <Type>:: Push (Type &val)
{
    if (top+1<maxsize)
        stack [++top]=val;
}
```

Errors:

> MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol `_WinMain@16` referenced in function `___tmainCRTStartup`

What Should I do?

Comment: Is this all the code?  Where is your main function?

Comment: Also looks like the type of project is set wrong. The linker error regarding WinMain implies you tried to create a Win32 project. If you just want something to output text to the command prompt, try changing the project type to Console.

Comment: By the way, if you are getting compiler/linker errors, you are not "running" the code.

Comment: I tried changing the project type, but project=exe worked instead of console.

Answer (score 400):

Thats a linker problem.

Try to change Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem (in Visual Studio).

from *Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)* to *Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)*

[This one helped me](http://cipaterson.wordpress.com/2007/09/30/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-_winmain16-referenced-in-function-___tmaincrtstartup/)

Comment: I've got the same issue. Your answer isn't helping. Any Other suggestion?

Comment: I had that problem when using MS Visual Studio. If your environment is different that you might have to fix it differently.
But it should still be a linker problem.

Comment: If you are using `tWinMain` as your main function, you must include tchar.h  _or_ change it to either `WinMain` or `wWinMain` depending on whether or not your app is Unicode. Failure to do so also yields this linker error even with the correct subsystem. (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

Comment: This helped me, apart from that I also had to disable **Avast** anti-virus.

Comment: Remember to not just change SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS to SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE. But the entire thing, I forgot to change Windows to Console before the parenthesis.

Comment: For anyone who cares why, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316433/difference-between-console-subsystemconsole-and-windows-subsystemwindows

Comment: You really saved my life, i was stuck during an hour on that problem !! Thank you !!!

Comment: This worked only after I selected "all configurations" for both platform and type.  Selecting "build" on the "Solution" attempted to build all and the first one tried was NOT the one had specified for console subsystem.

Comment: To anyone using VS for the first time: you need to right-click on the project/solution to get the Properties option, it's not on the Menu bar

Comment: That helped my program compile. Why is windows so finicky? I usually compile with GCC on VSL but I'm doing a famous tutorial. I tried compiling with native tools but I got a logical error. I wanted to see if that error would come up in VS. Yes, but to get to that point I had to create solution and change GUI settings. Does windows really have to be this complicated?

Answer (score 91):

As the others mentioned you can change the SubSystem to Console and the error will go away.

Or if you want to keep the Windows subsystem you can just hint at what your entry point is, because you haven't defined `___tmainCRTStartup`. You can do this by adding the following to *Properties -> Linker -> Command line*:

> /ENTRY:"mainCRTStartup"

This way you get rid of the console window.

Comment: +1: "This way you get rid of the console window." - Cool! Learned sth. new today!

Comment: +1 for the advice, i was trying to figure this out for like 20 minutes, since with SFML i can just specify the sub system Windows, With GLFW that obviously differen't so thanks (=

Answer (score 16):

Besides changing it to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` as others have said, you may need to change the **entry point** in Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point. Set it to **mainCRTStartup**.

It seems that Visual Studio might be searching for the WinMain function instead of main, if you don't specify otherwise.

Answer (score 15):

If you are having this problem and are using Qt - you need to link qtmain.lib or qtmaind.lib

Comment: That's on Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input.
Add `$(QTDIR)\lib\qtmaind.lib` to Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Adding `CONFIG += console` to the `.pro` file fixed the issue for my Qt project

Comment: Note that in QT6 qtmain.lib is gone. So you msut use "Morten Kristensen" answers to fix this.

Answer (score 10):

Include `<tchar.h>` which has the line:

```
#define _tWinMain wWinMain
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use Unicode Character Set, but the entry wasn't set, you can specify /ENTRY:"wWinMainCRTStartup"

Comment: life saver for me ! I was using cmake + mfc (unicode)

Answer (score 6):

If you actually want to use **_tWinMain()** instead of **main()**,
make sure your project has the relevant configuration:

Right click on Project (not Solution or source file) > Properties:

1. Linker -> System -> SubSystem => Windows(/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)
2. C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions => Replace _CONSOLE with _WINDOWS
3. In the c/cpp file where **_tWinMain()** is defined, add:

   `#include <Windows.h>`
   `#include <tchar.h>`

Answer (score 4):

i don't see the main function.

please make sure that it has main function.

example :

```
int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]){

}
```

hope that it works well. :)

Comment: This doesn't help. The linker is complaining about an undefined [WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559.aspx) entry point. Defining an entry point called `main` does nothing to solve that.

Comment: The linker tries to resolve different `main`/`WinMain` versions, and if none of them is found it says _WinMain@16 not found_, but this message isn't exactly correct.

Answer (score 4):

If your project is Dll, then the case might be that linker wants to build a console program. Open the project properties. Select the General settings. Select configuration type Dynamic Library there(.dll).

Comment: I have exactly that problem but though the `.dll` is set compiler is still trying to build windows app.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where to post this answer of mine but I think it's the right place.
I came across this very error today and switching the subsystems didn't change a thing.

Changing the 64bit lib files to 32bit (x86) did the trick for me, I hope it will help someone out there !

Comment: I tried this and worked, although a recompile of dependencies to the same targets also works.

Comment: also worked for me... seems like the unit test wizard uses a 32 bit entry point

Answer (score 2):

Your tried to turn that source file into an executable, which obviously isn't possible, because the mandatory entry point, the `main` function, isn't defined. Add a file main.cpp and define a main function. If you're working on the commandline (which I doubt), you can add `/c` to only compile and not link. This will produce an object file only, which needs to be linked into either a static or shared lib or an application (in which case you'll need an oject file with main defined).

`_WinMain` is Microsoft's name for `main` when linking.

Also: you're not running the code yet, you are *compiling* (and linking) it. C++ is not an interpreted language.

Comment: Actually, he needs a [`WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, INT)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) entry point. This linker error indicates that the project is being built for the Windows subsystem, not the console subsystem.

Comment: @Adam: ah yes, I've been spoiled by Qt :) (which effectively hides WinMain from you).

Comment: WinMain is only for Windows applications.  Console apps use a different name _tmain, which resolves to main or wmain depending on Unicode/MBCS setting.

Comment: @AdamMaras, perfect. I was looking for the requisite capitalization and prototype. It works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: `_WinMain@16` is the decorated symbol of the user-provided entry point called by the startup code in the CRT, when targeting the Windows subsystem. It's not *"Microsoft's name for `main` when linking"*. If you target the console subsystem, the CRT that ships with Visual Studio will call an entry point named `main`. If undefined, the linker will complain about a missing symbol called `_main`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CMake, you can also get this error when you set `SET(GUI_TYPE WIN32)` on a console application.

Answer (score 0):

The erudite suggestions mentioned above will solve the problem in 99.99% of the cases.  It was my luck that they did not.  In my case it turned out I was including a header file from a different Windows project.  Sure enough, at the very bottom of that file I found the directive:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:Windows")
```

Needless to say, removing this line solved my problem.