# difference between Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) and Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

can somebody please explain difference between those two declarations in the properties of the  linker in visual studio 2008( please as simple as possible, I'm new in the world of C++) thanks in advace

edit: if possible can you give me please two small programs to show an effect

Comment: A related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716350/effects-of-switching-between-subsystemconsole-to-subsystemwindows-in-a-dll

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` is for console based applications. You should define `main` function in code.

`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)` is for GUI applications. You should define `WinMain` function.

Comment: SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS isn't necessarily for GUI apps. Just for apps without a console. Think server apps, services that run headless.

Comment: If targeting Windows XP from MSVC 2013 command line, you may need /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.1 (or :CONSOLE,5.1)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS isn't necessarily for GUI apps either. It can  call AllocConsole() if it needs a console.

What happens is that for /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE console setup (and I think stdout/stdin setup) happen automatically.

So  /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS is  for apps without an **automatically allocated** console

Comment: A DLL without specifying `/SUBSYSTEM` (i.e. select NOT SET in Visual Studio) still has the SUBSYSTEM field set to `Windows GUI`. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716350/effects-of-switching-between-subsystemconsole-to-subsystemwindows-in-a-dll

Answer (score 8):

CONSOLE: Console window is shown. WINDOWS - program starts without Console window.

Edited, looking at another answers. Notice that /SUBSYSTEM flag doesn't affect the program entry point. Program entry point is defined by /ENTRY linker option. Usually /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE has "main" entry point, and /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS has "WinMain" entry point. But it is possible, for example, to create GUI application with WinMain entry point and Console window.

Comment: The default entry point for `/subsystem:console` is `[w]mainCRTStartup`, for `/subsystem:windows` it's `[w]WinMainCRTStartup`. It just so happens that the CRT implements those two functions and these implementations call `main` and `WinMain`, respectively. Thus, `main` and `WinMain` become the entry point for the programmer with which the linker as (almost) nothing to do. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=vs-2017

Comment: Seems somewhat contrary to what the official documentation says: "The choice of subsystem affects the entry point symbol (or entry point function) that the linker will select".

Comment: @Sam There are actually several values for `/SUBSYSTEM`. Choosing different one will cause the linker to search for different symbols.

Answer (score 4):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx). VS2008 automates some things for you which has lead to the confusion.

> **CONSOLE** Win32 character-mode application. The operating system
>   provides a console for console applications. If main or wmain is
>   defined for native code, int main(array ^) is defined for
>   managed code, or you build the application completely by using
>   /clr:safe, **CONSOLE** is the default.
>
> **WINDOWS** Application does not require a console, probably because it creates its own windows for interaction with the user. If WinMain
>   or wWinMain is defined for native code, or WinMain(HISTANCE *,
>   HINSTANCE *, char *, int) or wWinMain(HINSTANCE *, HINSTANCE *,
>   wchar_t *, int) is defined for managed code, **WINDOWS** is the default.

Answer (score 3):

/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE results in a process with a console and /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS does not.

Comment: This is not entirely true. E.g. a process with `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` can have a console if it calls `AllocConsole()`

Answer (score 1):

My solution in 2023 with SDL2 and VSCode, compiling with mingw32:

For the production build I use the flag `-mwindows` which prevents `std::cout` and `printf` from being printed anywhere.

To debug I change the flag `-mwindows` to `-Wl,-subsystem,console` to allow `std::cout` and `printf` to be printed in a console window.