# Effects of switching between /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE to /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS in a DLL

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, dll

I couldn't find anything useful on the MSDN for this case. Using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), in the module list, I see a mixed usage of Console and GUI.

Does this have an impact when compiling a DLL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This option only has an effect on applications (`exe`), not on libraries(`dll`).

Its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) says:

> The `/SUBSYSTEM` option specifies the environment for the executable.
>
> The choice of subsystem affects the entry point symbol (or entry point
>   function) that the linker will select.

This does not affect libraries, which have their own (optional) [entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx).

*Additional information following CyberShadow's comment:* The subsystem field itself seems to be ignored when a DLL is loaded. [This article about CSRSS](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/?p=492) says (emphasis mine):

> Furthermore, **each process is associated with one, certain subsystem**;
>   this property is being set by the linker (during the compilation
>   process), and resides in the following PE structure field: [...]

Comment: the /SUBSYSTEM flag is put in the image file - exe, dll, sys, ....by the linker when building an application. This flag exist exist BOTH for EXE and DLL images! Take a look at the Visual Studio Linker Settings -> Substem

Comment: This flag affect ANY image file. Take a look at many \system32\*.dll (e.g. NTDLL.DLL which is tagged with the /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

Comment: @mox, all image files contain this flag, but it does not affect the entry point of libraries. As you can see, `ntdll.dll` can be loaded in the address space of both console and Windows executables without ill effects.

Comment: This flag has an impact on how the Windows Loader will handle the image. It documents the expectations of the image in regard of the Win32 subsystem (which is implemented in CSRSS.EXE).

Comment: Frédéric, your answer appears to be based on an incomplete understanding of the question, and you do not seem to understand mox's comments either. Every PE file (EXE, DLL, SYS...) has a header field (specifically, IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.Subsystem), which apparently can take over a dozen meaningful distinct values (see the IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_* enum). The `/SUBSYSTEM` linker option does more than choose an entry point, it also populates the `Subsystem` field in the header. The question was: when loading a DLL, does the `Subsystem` field *in the DLL itself* have any effect?

Comment: @CyberShadow, it's been a while since I posted this, so it's not easy to go back to my reasoning at the time. If I understand your comment correctly, the questioner wants to know if the subsystem header field has an impact when loading a DLL. From the information I could gather, that's not the case. I updated my answer accordingly, please follow up if I missed the point again.

Answer (score 5):

My below reply is just some findings.

I tried to create below types of project within VS2015:

- Win32 console app project
- Win32 DLL project
- Win32 Windows app project

Below are their complete linking options:

**Win32 console app project**

> /OUT:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe"
> /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT
> /PDB:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.pdb"
> /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
> "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib"
> "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86
> /INCREMENTAL
> /PGD:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.pgd"
> **/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE** /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
> /ManifestFile:"Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe.intermediate.manifest"
> /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

**Win32 DLL project**

> /OUT:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\Win32DLLProject1.dll"
> /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT
> /PDB:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\Win32DLLProject1.pdb"
> /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
> "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib"
> "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib"
> /IMPLIB:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\Win32DLLProject1.lib"
> /DEBUG **/DLL** /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL
> /PGD:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\Win32DLLProject1.pgd"
> **/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS** /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
> /ManifestFile:"Debug\Win32DLLProject1.dll.intermediate.manifest"
> /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

**Win32 Windows app project**

> /OUT:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\Win32WindowsProject1.exe"
> /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT
> /PDB:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\Win32WindowsProject1.pdb"
> /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
> "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib"
> "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86
> /INCREMENTAL
> /PGD:"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\Win32WindowsProject1.pgd"
> **/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS** /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
> /ManifestFile:"Debug\Win32WindowsProject1.exe.intermediate.manifest"
> /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

So we can see, for a `/DLL`, `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is defined.

Then I tried to build a DLL with 3 different SUBSYSTEM values:

- CONSOLE
- WINDOWS
- NOT SET

There are other values as well, but I can only build successfully with the above 3. Other values will lead to linking errors, which means some external symbols are needed.

The full list of possible SUBSYSTEM values is:

[image]

You can use the CFF Explorer to inspect the PE/COFF binaries.

The `SUBSYSTEM` header field locates at the file offset `0x14C` of a PE/COFF file. It is part of the `Optional Header`.

**/DLL /SUBSYESTEM:CONSOLE**

[image]

**/DLL /SUBSYESTEM:WINDOWS**

[image]

**/DLL and no /SUBSYESTEM option (by selecting NOT SET in VS2015 project properties page**

[image]

Interestingly, the `NOT SET` and `WINDOWS` values lead to the same content in the binary header.

And I compared the whole binary of the 3 DLLs. It seems the rest of the binaries are all the same, except for some timestamp and debug info.

**This is just some fact I found. How `/SUBSYSTEM` option affects the binary behavior depends on how the loader interprets this field.**

In one of the projects I participated in, the `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` and `/DLL` are used together, which is different from the default combination for a DLL project. But it seems nothing bad happens. So I agree with @Frédéric Hamidi that this flag has no functional impact to a DLL.