# Significance of /SUBSYSTEM parameter - msdn

Tags: c++, c, windows, sdk, operating-system

As per the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk(v=vs.100).aspx

32 bit app  is suppose to use 4.00(minimum) and 64 bit app is suppose to use 5.02(minimum)

But I would like to understand the significance/meaning of this parameter and the below statement from that link.

“The choice of subsystem affects the entry point symbol (or entry point function) that the linker will select.”

Sham

Comment: There is no `dlli_ntversion` according to Google. Furthermore, your edit has made this a **completely** different question. I think you should roll back the edit and ask a new question with the wording of the current edit.

Comment: A related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716350/effects-of-switching-between-subsystemconsole-to-subsystemwindows-in-a-dll

Answer (score 4):

Simply put: if you’re writing a console application you need to specify `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` and if you’re writing a windowed application which doesn’t automatically open a console window, you need `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`. Other subsystems specify that your application runs in kernel mode (but that’s not simply possible), interfaces directly with the hardware or runs on a Windows CE device.

The versions rarely need to be specified.

The executable created by the linker simply has a flag set depending on this option, and the Windows function responsible for launching your application inspects this flag to determine how to launch your application (with a console window attached etc.).

Comment: i rephrased my question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your program you have `main`, `_tmain` and `WinMain` etc. This is were your program starts. However this is not the *true* entry point where the program start, it's just a function that is called from the runtime linked to your program. In the runtime, there is usually a special function that does some initialization needed before your main function is called, this is the "entry point" referenced in the documentation.

The subsystem setting seems to tell the linker to use different "entry point" functions depending on its setting.

Comment: Not really. The entry point is related but the subsystem tells the linker which *true* entry point is chosen, i.e. *how* the program is created in memory. For instance, whether it is attached to a console or whether it creates its own windows. So more than just determining the application entry point, it determines the *type* of application and which context it can be launched from.

Comment: Hello People                                                             msdn link also says , i see that 4.00 and 5.02 values are given for 32/64 bit respectively, what does these all about?                                       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk(v=vs.100).aspx              Sham

Answer (score 0):

The primary significance of the subsystem parameter is to determine which subsystem the executable will be built for; whether it will be a console application, a Windows application, a POSIX application, a device driver, and so on.

According to the documentation, the version numbers specify the minimum operating system (or subsystem) version that the executable requires.  For example, if you specified 6.0 (Windows Vista) then, in theory, Windows XP would refuse to attempt to run the executable.  I am not certain whether or not this is actually true, and I don't think it is common practice to specify a minimum operating system version this way.

The impact on the entry point is described a little sloppily; it would be more accurate to say that the choice of subsystem affects the *default* entry point.  You can override this default with the [`/ENTRY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) parameter.

As documented under `/ENTRY`, the default settings are as follows:

- `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`: mainCRTStartup (or wmainCRTStartup)
- `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`: WinMainCRTStartup (or wWinMainCRTStartup)
- `/DLL`: _DllMainCRTStartup

It also says: "If the /DLL or /SUBSYSTEM option is not specified, the linker selects a subsystem and entry point depending on whether main or WinMain is defined."

IIRC, other subsystems have no default entry point and you must explicitly use the `/ENTRY` option.

Comment: i rephrased my question,  sorry for that

Comment: in the same pasted msdn link, i see that 4.00 and 5.02 values are given for 32/64 bit respectively, what does these all about?

Comment: The minimum version number for x64 code is 5.2 because prior to Windows version 5.2 (aka Windows XP) there was no support for the x64 platform.  (Note that version 5.2 is the same as version 5.02, that's just a different formatting.)