# Running NI-IMAQ and WINAPI requires 2 different SubSystems

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to implement WINAPI into a function of NI-IMAQ. However, NI-IMAQ requires my SubSystem in Visual Studio to be Console as shown below.

Whereas WINAPI requires the SubSystem to be Windows.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

[image]

The following is my code:

```
int main()

{
  INTERFACE_ID interfaceID;

  SESSION_ID sessionID;

  unsigned int bitsPerPixel, plotFlag;

  if (imgInterfaceOpen("img0", &interfaceID) == IMG_ERR_GOOD) // "img0" is interfacename, opens an interface named img0

  {
    std::cout << "Interface is open" << std::endl;
    if (imgSessionOpen(interfaceID, &sessionID) == IMG_ERR_GOOD)

    {
        std::cout << "Session is open" << std::endl;

        // 30 sept 2021: try GRAB
        // 1. imgInterfaceOpen (DONE)
        // 2. imgSessionOpen (DONE)
        // 3. imgGrabSetup (DONE)
        // 4. imgSessionStartAcquisition (DONE)
        // 5. imgGrab (DONE)
        // 6. User specific functions
        // 7. imgSessionStop Acquisition (DONE)
        // 8. imgClose (DONE)

        //3. imgGrabSetup
        imgGrabSetup(sessionID, TRUE); //manually start acquisition with imgSessionStartAcquisition

        //4. imgSessionStartAcquisition
        imgSessionStartAcquisition(sessionID);

        //5. imgGrab (sessionID, buffer address, uint32 waitForNext)
        imgGrab(sessionID, NULL, TRUE);

        // imgSessionSaveBufferEx to save a buffer of a session to PNG
        imgSessionSaveBufferEx(sessionID, NULL, reinterpret_cast<Int8*>(const_cast<char*>("test.png")));
        std::cout << "Image saved" << std::endl;



        // get attributes to get pixel depth of camera
        imgGetAttribute(sessionID, IMG_ATTR_BITSPERPIXEL, &bitsPerPixel); // obtain pixel depth, then store in bitsPerPixel
        std::cout << "Get Attribute" << std::endl;
        // declare plotFlag according to pixel depth, bitsPerPixel
        switch (bitsPerPixel)
        {
        case 10:
            plotFlag = IMGPLOT_MONO_10;
            break;
        case 12:
            plotFlag = IMGPLOT_MONO_12;
            break;
        case 14:
            plotFlag = IMGPLOT_MONO_14;
            break;
        case 16:
            plotFlag = IMGPLOT_MONO_16;
            break;
        case 24:
        case 32:
            // assumes that a 24 bits camera is a color camera.
            // in this mode, even if the camera is 24 bits the board returns 32 bits values
            plotFlag = IMGPLOT_COLOR_RGB32;
            break;
        default:
            plotFlag = IMGPLOT_MONO_8;
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "plotFlag obtained" << std::endl;
        //6. functions or display using imgPlot (1. GUIHNDL window, 2. void* buffer, 3. uInt32 leftBufOffset, 4. uInt32 topBufOffset, 5. uInt32 xsize, 6. uInt32 ysize, 
        // 7. uInt32 xpos, 8. uInt32 ypos, 9. uInt32 flags)


        //            1          2   3  4      5              6           7           8          9
        imgPlot2(ImaqSmplHwnd, NULL, 0, 0, AcqWinWidth, AcqWinHeight, CanvasLeft, CanvasTop, plotFlag);
        std::cout << "imgPlot2 done" << std::endl;

        //7. imgSessionStop Acquisition
        imgSessionStopAcquisition(sessionID);
        std::cout << "Stop acquisition" << std::endl;
        
        imgClose(sessionID, FALSE); // closes the session using the imgClose function
        std::cout << "Session is closed" << std::endl;

    }

    imgClose(interfaceID, FALSE);   // closes the interface using the imgClose function
    std::cout << "Interface is closed" << std::endl;

   }
}




 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// 2.  this is the window event callback function from line 15  , first parameter is window handler
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM param, LPARAM lparam);

// this is the main function
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE currentInstance, HINSTANCE previousInstance, LPSTR cmdLine, INT cmdCount) 
{

   // 1. Register the window class
   const char* CLASS_NAME = "myWin32WindowClass";
   WNDCLASS wc{};
   wc.hInstance = currentInstance;
   wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
   wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
   wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
   wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcessMessages; // every window requires a programmer defined callback function that is called by the OS when an event happens ie. close window, click inside window
   RegisterClass(&wc);

   // 3.  Create the window
   CreateWindow(CLASS_NAME, "Win32 Tutorial",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,           // Window style
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,               // Window initial position
    800, 600,                       // Window size
    nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

   //  4. Lastly,    Window loop - all graphical applications need a loop that runs until application is closed 
   MSG msg{}; // empty window message, while loop runs as long as GetMessage returns TRUE
   while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) 
   {
       TranslateMessage(&msg);
       //return MessageBox(NULL, "hello, world", "caption", 0);
       DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }

return 0;
}

// 2. 
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM param, LPARAM lparam) 
{
   switch (msg) {
   case WM_DESTROY: //user pressed cross button at top right corner
       PostQuitMessage(0);
       return 0;
   default:
       return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, param, lparam);
   }
}
```

There are int main() and int WINAPI WinMain(), which runs alright **separately**.
However, the code in int main() can only run when the Subsystem is Console, whereas the code in int WINAPI WinMain() can only run when the Subsystem is Windows. Is there a way to integrate the 2 into 1 or are they conflicting?

Comment: "WINAPI requires the SubSystem to be Windows" is wrong, SubSystem only determines if your app is a console app or a windowed app, but it's not clear what you're trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316433/difference-between-console-subsystemconsole-and-windows-subsystemwindows

Comment: i have edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: They are exclusive. If you need a "permanent" window, choose subsystem Windows, keep `winmain`, and run the `main` code somewhere else (like in another thread), it depends on your context

Comment: okay, i understand what you mean by them being exclusive. so i tried putting some of the functions from my main code into winmain and it works so far. I'm gonna try implementing the rest of it. thanks for your guidance!

Comment: you should answer your self and close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be one subsystem in place. As a window is meant to be displayed, use the Windows subsystem.

Between int main() and int WINAPI WinMain(), use int WINAPI WinMain() as the main function and include the function calls from int main().

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.