# Cannot open include file: 'basewin.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, directx, visual-c++-2013

I'm trying to figure out how I can find where to either download the file set or get rid of this error. This elusive 'basewin.h' is nowhere to be found. So I don't know if I'm missing a library or what. I've also tried switching around the 'windows.h' and 'basewin.h' statements. I've tried disabling precompiled headers. Apparently this file holds the information for the "basewindow" class.

I'm using visual studio 2013 and I'm using a win32 project.I'm trying to run the example from the microsoft tutorial website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684181(v=vs.85).aspx. Any help would be very much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")

#include "basewin.h"

template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}

class MainWindow : public BaseWindow<MainWindow>
{
    ID2D1Factory            *pFactory;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget   *pRenderTarget;
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush    *pBrush;
    D2D1_ELLIPSE            ellipse;

    void    CalculateLayout();
    HRESULT CreateGraphicsResources();
    void    DiscardGraphicsResources();
    void    OnPaint();
    void    Resize();

public:

    MainWindow() : pFactory(NULL), pRenderTarget(NULL), pBrush(NULL)
    {
    }

    PCWSTR  ClassName() const { return L"Circle Window Class"; }
    LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

// Recalculate drawing layout when the size of the window changes.

void MainWindow::CalculateLayout()
{
    if (pRenderTarget != NULL)
    {
        D2D1_SIZE_F size = pRenderTarget->GetSize();
        const float x = size.width / 2;
        const float y = size.height / 2;
        const float radius = min(x, y);
        ellipse = D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(x, y), radius, radius);
    }
}

HRESULT MainWindow::CreateGraphicsResources()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (pRenderTarget == NULL)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(m_hwnd, &rc);

        D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom);

        hr = pFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
            D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hwnd, size),
            &pRenderTarget);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            const D2D1_COLOR_F color = D2D1::ColorF(1.0f, 1.0f, 0);
            hr = pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(color, &pBrush);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                CalculateLayout();
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

void MainWindow::DiscardGraphicsResources()
{
    SafeRelease(&pRenderTarget);
    SafeRelease(&pBrush);
}

void MainWindow::OnPaint()
{
    HRESULT hr = CreateGraphicsResources();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        BeginPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);

        pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

        pRenderTarget->Clear( D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::SkyBlue) );
        pRenderTarget->FillEllipse(ellipse, pBrush);

        hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
        if (FAILED(hr) || hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
        {
            DiscardGraphicsResources();
        }
        EndPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
    }
}

void MainWindow::Resize()
{
    if (pRenderTarget != NULL)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(m_hwnd, &rc);

        D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom);

        pRenderTarget->Resize(size);
        CalculateLayout();
        InvalidateRect(m_hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
    }
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    MainWindow win;

    if (!win.Create(L"Circle", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(win.Window(), nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT MainWindow::HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        if (FAILED(D2D1CreateFactory(
                D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pFactory)))
        {
            return -1;  // Fail CreateWindowEx.
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        DiscardGraphicsResources();
        SafeRelease(&pFactory);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        OnPaint();
        return 0;


    case WM_SIZE:
        Resize();
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/ujentus/D2DSample/blob/master/basewin.h) help?

Comment: That allows it to compile but then I get a linking error. I think I'm missing a library.

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Comment: Yeah, you would - that link was just the header file, but wasn't sure if it had what you needed in it.  Have a look for basewin.dll on google?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626397/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-winmain16-referenced-in-function)

Comment: It's got to be in some other package or something when i google basewin.h there are basically no hits on google. There's also nothing on basewin.dll. It's like it doesn't exist. You would think that for this microsoft tutorial that you'd see more on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page you linked says: "The program re-uses the BaseWindow class that was defined in the topic [Managing Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#basewindow)".

That link contains the code for the `BaseWindow` class, which you should put in basewin.h.

Comment: Awesome! Was wondering where some of the other links got their basewin.h code from.

Comment: 'Thanks' alot. I thought I was lost forever This is completely correct. It's funny I just overlooked this. In regards to the linker error you need to use the standard windows entry point and not the visual studio default entry point ex:


<code>

Incorrect: int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)



'Correct:' int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int nCmdShow)</code>

Comment: `Incorrect: int APIENTRY tWinMain(_In HINSTANCE hInstance, In_opt HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, In LPTSTR lpCmdLine, In int nCmdShow) 


'Correct:' int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int nCmdShow`