# LNK2019 WinMain16@ error, can't fix it

Tags: c++, windows

I searched it up and it has been asked a bilion times for many different situations. But mine is simply one: i try to compile a simple EMPTY file and i get this error:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

There are people saying that is about the difference of the subsystem between console and windows, but i tried both, in both win32 console application and in console application but the error is the same, with some or without any code in the source file. I repeat, the file is empty and i get this error. Can somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626397/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-winmain16-referenced-in-function

Comment: Isn't Google wonderful!

Comment: Not when you try all what you find but nothing works and the error still occours.

Comment: A C++ program must have a main function. A single EMPTY file by definition cannot have a main function.

Answer (score 0):

A C++ program must define `main`. If all you have is an empty file then you obviously haven't done that.

What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: As i said i tried even like that but the error still occours. It happened a 2 hours ago when i used a int vec[2] and i got this error and now i can't fix it in any way, shape or form and damn i'm so stucked now.

Comment: @Nicola36631 if the code linked, and after a modification it didn't, odds are good that the modification somehow hid main. Maybe the brackets were gooned. Can't say. Post code.