# Error in Visual studio 2015 after installing SFML

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, sfml

recently **I've installe SFML for Visual studio 2015**. I have read the tutorial for this specific task on there web site but after the test (compiling and running debug) **this error show up**:

https://pastebin.com/mY7r7zy9

```
1>------ Build started: Project: projet game, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
1>C:\Users\Cewein\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\projet game\Debug\projet game.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

why and what should i do ? 
should i rename my main.cpp to winmain.cpp ?

thanks you for the help

P.S: VS2015 is one the main drive where the OS is (C:) but SFML the folder is on another drive (E:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol \_WinMain@16 referenced in function \_\_\_tmainCRTStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626397/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-winmain16-referenced-in-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subsystem is set to Windows (`/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`), you need to link `sfml-main`, which will define `WinMain()` and call `main()`.

If your subsystem is set to Console (`/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`), then you don't need to link `sfml-main`.

To change the subsystem, go to your project settings, then Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem