# Linker error "unresolved external symbol _main" with Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

Does anyone know how to fix this error? All I have is a header file and a source file for a class.

1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

#include <iostream>

class Point {
public:
    Point();
    Point(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
    bool operator== (const Point &other) const;

    unsigned int m_x;
    unsigned int m_y;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &sout, const Point &pt);
};

#endif
```

AND

```
#include "Point.h"


Point::Point() {}  // Needed because of existence of other constructors

Point::Point(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
}

// Note: automatically get copy constructor

bool
Point::operator== (const Point &other) const {
    return (m_x == other.m_x && m_y == other.m_y);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &sout, const Point &pt) {
    sout << "(" << pt.m_x << ", " << pt.m_y << ")";
    return sout;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost 6 years late but I see two possible causes (Given the code that is presented)

Hopefully, this is useful to others who stumble upon a similar issue.

1. You are trying to build a library but the project type is set to Application(.exe)
2. You are building an Application(.exe) but have neglected to provide a main function.

I have done this many times as I have created a single project that I use as a template for Visual Studio and its default is set to Application(.exe) and sometimes I neglect to change it to Library(.lib) when I need to make a library.

What is happening here is that the C runtime (The code is in the MSVCRTD.LIB) contains a function called `invoke_main()` whose job it is to call the main() function in your application specific code. Because the source code didn't contain a function called `main()` the linker gives the "Unresolved external symbol ..." error

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a linker error, probably related to #include or conflicting definitions.
Can't say much more without code.

Comment: I don't see any issues in the code. In fact the error message doesn't even seem to point at your "point" file. I would assume it's a problem with your IDE, you are either compiling another project or some other file that shouldn't be there is getting compiled with the rest. Should look into "MSVCRTD.lib". Could also be project settings.

Comment: That is why I can't figure out what is wrong. And there is no other project. I made a new project and made sure all others were deleted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626397/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-winmain16-referenced-in-function
This might help you?