# I Had an But It Wasn't In a file I could get to, and another one I dont know how to fix

Tags: c++

The error said: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int_cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) The page was MSVCRTD.lib(exe.winmai... (the whole thing did not show) and on line 1. All I know is that on the file the problem was, line 1 was `#include<iostream>` . THe second error was: 1 unresolved externals on the file I was working on, also on line 1.

Other Info:
Programming Language: C++
Platform: Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Let me know in the comments if you need any more info.

Comment: Start a new project. Include the MINIMAL amount of code that reproduces the error. [example] My best guess without more info is that you're missing a `main` function? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6626397/2027196

Comment: Oops, this seems to be the issue https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC3 "Some directive names require arguments; these make up the rest of the directive line and must be separated from the directive name by whitespace." You're missing a space between `#include` and `<iostream>` Although I can't find the corresponding requirement in the visual studio docs.